# TypeName in VBScript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

I need to convert following lines of vbscript codes to javascripts,
`If TypeName(document.all(cFieldName)) = "HTMLInputElement" Then`
and

```
ElseIf TypeName(document.all(cFieldName)) = "HTMLSelectElement" Then
```

I have tried `if(typeof $("#" + (cFieldName)) === "HTMLInputElement")` and `else if(typeof $("#" + cFieldName) === "HTMLSelectElement")` but they are not working.

Comment: Get and process some introductory Javascript teaching material, first. In this case, start by finding out what "typeof" actually does, what it returns. The strings you check for are not even part of the repertoire :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, you can do this:

```js
if (document.all[cFieldName].nodeName === "INPUT") {
    // It's an input element
}
```

and

```js
if (document.all[cFieldName].nodeName === "SELECT") {
    // It's a select element
}
```

(That assumes HTML, rather than XHTML. In XHTML, the names will be lower case. To avoid messing myself up, I usually throw `.toUpperCase()` in there.)

As you've discovered, `typeof` will just give you `"object"`. It's *possible* that on some engines, `Object.prototype.toString.call(document.all[cFieldName])` might give you `"HTMLInputElement"`, but I wouldn't expect it to be reliable cross-browser (and I assume one reason this code is being translated is to run it on browsers other than IE). There's more on various ways of figuring out what things are in JavaScript (though not specifically in regard to HTML elements) in my blog post [*Say what?*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/say-what.html).

Comment: Instead of `.all` you could use `$("#selector").get(0).nodeName`

Comment: @SalmanA: Or even better, `$("#selector")[0].nodeName` (although `document.all` on IE has things in it by their `name` as well as by their `id` so an `id` selector may not be the right thing). I have to admit I didn't even notice the `jquery` tag and was just focussing on the `typeof` aspect. :-)